# Navigation toolbar not showing up on the window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to place the navigation toolbar in the canvas window. But only the toolbar shows up when I tried running the code. The lines I tried are also included below with `#`. How can this be fixed?

The code is executable. The values of the first window have been assigned, just click "Click" button.

```
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


window=Tk()


def open_window1():
    y = 1/2
    b = 1/4

    result = []
    u = []
    v = []

    t = []
    p = [0,25,43.3013,50,43.3013,25,0,0,0,0,0,0]

    a = []

    pn = []
    pn.append(0)



    x = 0.0
    for i in range(11):
        z = x
        t.append("%.1f" % z)
        x = x + 0.1

    m = 45594/100000
    k = 18
    c = 0.2865

    u.append(0)
    v.append(0)


    a.append((p[0]-c*v[0]-k*u[0])/m)

    dt = 0.1

    a1 =(m/(b*dt*dt)+y*c/(b*dt))
    a2 = (m/(b*dt)+(y/b-1)*c)
    a3 = (((1/(2*b))-1)*m + dt*((y/(2*b))-1)*c)
    kn = k + a1


    for i in range(len(t)-1):
        pn.append(np.around(p[i+1]+ a1*u[i] + a2*v[i] + a3*a[i], decimals=4))

        u.append(np.around(pn[i+1]/kn, decimals=4))

        v.append(np.around(y*(u[i+1]-u[i])/(b*dt) + (1-y/b)*v[i] + dt* (1-y/(2*b))*a[i], decimals=4))
        a.append(np.around((u[i+1]-u[i])/(b*dt*dt) - v[i]/(b*dt)-(1/(2*b)-1)*a[i], decimals=4))


    top = tk.Toplevel()
    top.wm_geometry("1400x594")
    top.title('Result table')

    canvas = tk.Canvas(top,bg="white", width=1395, height=594)
    canvas.grid(row=0,column=180)

    #b1 = tk.Label(canvas, text="ti")
    #b1.grid(row=3, column=0)

    #b2 = tk.Label(canvas, text="Pi")
    #b2.grid(row=3, column=200)

    b1 = tk.Label(canvas, text="ti", font= "calibri 13", bg="white")
    canvas.create_window(3,3, window=b1, anchor=tk.NW)   

    b2 = tk.Label(canvas, text="Pi", font= "calibri 13", bg="white")
    canvas.create_window(150,3, window=b2, anchor=tk.NW)   

    b6 = tk.Label(canvas, text="Pni", font= "calibri 13", bg="white")
    canvas.create_window(300,3, window=b6, anchor=tk.NW)      

    b3 = tk.Label(canvas, text="u''i", font= "calibri 13", bg="white")
    canvas.create_window(450,3, window=b3, anchor=tk.NW)   

    b4 = tk.Label(canvas, text="u'i", font= "calibri 13", bg="white")
    canvas.create_window(600,3, window=b4, anchor=tk.NW)   

    b5 = tk.Label(canvas, text="ui", font= "calibri 13", bg="white")
    canvas.create_window(750,3, window=b5, anchor=tk.NW)   


    for i in range(1,len(t)):

        b6 = tk.Label(canvas, text=t[i], font= "calibri 12", bg="white")
        canvas.create_window(3,50*i, window=b6, anchor=tk.NW)

    for i in range(1,len(t)):

        b6 = tk.Label(canvas, text=p[i], font= "calibri 12", bg="white")
        canvas.create_window(150,50*i, window=b6, anchor=tk.NW)            

    for i in range(1,len(t)):

        b6 = tk.Label(canvas, text=pn[i], font= "calibri 12", bg="white")
        canvas.create_window(300,50*i, window=b6, anchor=tk.NW)         

    for i in range(1,len(t)):

        b6 = tk.Label(canvas, text=a[i], font= "calibri 12", bg="white")
        canvas.create_window(450,50*i, window=b6, anchor=tk.NW)     


    for i in range(1,len(t)):

        b6 = tk.Label(canvas, text=v[i], font= "calibri 12", bg="white")
        canvas.create_window(600,50*i, window=b6, anchor=tk.NW)   

    for i in range(1,len(t)):

        b6 = tk.Label(canvas, text=u[i], font= "calibri 12", bg="white")
        canvas.create_window(750,50*i, window=b6, anchor=tk.NW)   


    f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
    q = f.add_subplot(111)
    q.plot(t,a)

    figure = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, canvas)
    figure.draw() 
    canvas.create_window(850, 3, window=figure.get_tk_widget(), anchor=tk.NW)

    #toolbar= NavigationToolbar2Tk(figure, canvas)
    #toolbar.update()
    #canvas.create_window(850, 800, window=figure._tkcanvas, anchor=tk.NW)



b2=Button(window, text="Click", width=12, command=open_window1)
b2.grid(row=5,column=0)


window.title("Fill in the blanks")
window.geometry("300x150")
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `NavigationToolbar2Tk(figure, canvas)`, the underlying method used is `pack` on the container `canvas`, which conflicts with the rest of your widgets created by `create_window` method. You need to create a `Frame` to hold your toolbar, then call `create_window` on the frame instead:

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x450")

fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
t = np.arange(0, 3, .01)
fig.add_subplot(111).plot(t, 2 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * t))

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(fill="both",expand=True)

figure_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root)
figure_canvas.draw()

toolbar_frame = tk.Frame(canvas)
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(figure_canvas, toolbar_frame)
toolbar.update()

canvas.create_window(0,0, window=figure_canvas.get_tk_widget(), anchor=tk.NW)
canvas.create_window(0,400, window=toolbar_frame, anchor=tk.NW)

root.mainloop()
```

But looking at your current setup, there is no actual need for all those calls of `create_window`. Instead you can simply line them up using `grid`, and create an extra frame to store the `toolbar`:

```
def open_window1():
    y = 1/2
    b = 1/4

    ...

    top = tk.Toplevel()
    top.wm_geometry("1400x594")
    top.title('Result table')

    canvas = tk.Canvas(top,bg="white", width=1395, height=594)
    canvas.grid(row=0,column=180)

    result_labels = ("ti","Pi","Pni","u''i", "u'i","ui")

    for num, txt in enumerate(result_labels):
        tk.Label(canvas, text=txt, font= "calibri 13", bg="white",width=10).grid(row=0,column=num,padx=12,pady=8)
        for col, item in enumerate([t,p,pn,a,v,u]):
            tk.Label(canvas, text=item[num], font="calibri 12", bg="white").grid(row=num+1,column=col,padx=12,pady=8)

    f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
    q = f.add_subplot(111)
    q.plot(t,a)

    figure = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, canvas)
    figure.draw()
    figure.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0,column=6,rowspan=7,padx=5,pady=2)

    tool_bar_frame = Frame(canvas)
    toolbar= NavigationToolbar2Tk(figure, tool_bar_frame)
    toolbar.update()
    tool_bar_frame.grid(row=7,column=6,pady=2)
```

Comment: This works but I wanted to learn to place the navigationtoolbar using canvas.create_window so I can precisely put it to the desired location.

Comment: The idea is the same - you will need to put it in a frame first. Then use `create_window` to place the frame.

Comment: I tried canvas.create_window(850, 800, window=figure._tkcanvas, anchor=tk.NW) but only the toolbar shows up and the table doesn't.